# Why does my Bluetooth adapters only allow connection to 5 BLE sensors?

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to connect 7 BLE sensors to my Raspberry Pi using an external bluetooth adapter. However, I can only connect 5 units simoustanely. I have tried with three different bluetooth adapters. Two Bluetooth 4.0 class 1 adapters and 1 Bluetooth 5.0 adapter.

Is there some kind of blocking in the adapter, or is it my Raspberry Pi that needs some tweeking?

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific limit in the BLE specification so it tends to be a design decision by the dongle manufacturer as they balance cost and performance. Dongles tend to only contain the necessary resources to maintain a small number of connections that cover the needs of most consumers. If you are lucky the dongle datasheet will specify this.